# Fatal Exception: java.lang.NullPointerException error occured randomly while using application

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, fatal-error

Sometime application having crash issue and my crash log show me Error like this :

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int android.support.v4.util.SparseArrayCompat.size()' on a null object reference
       at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onSaveInstanceState(FragmentActivity.java:570)
       at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.onSaveInstanceState(AppCompatActivity.java:480)
       at android.app.Activity.performSaveInstanceState(Activity.java:1495)
       at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnSaveInstanceState(Instrumentation.java:1316)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.callCallActivityOnSaveInstanceState(ActivityThread.java:5194)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.performStopActivityInner(ActivityThread.java:4519)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleStopActivity(ActivityThread.java:4582)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1300(ActivityThread.java:218)
       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1747)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6917)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1404)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1199)
```

how to fix this error??

please help me thanks in advance.

Comment: this error occurred in any screen not in only one screen and yes when we are  trying to test app doesn’t get crash issue but it will be occurred after app become live.

Comment: add your code to get help.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you are trying to get size() of an array object without null check on the object. set a null check to avoid this exception.

```
    if(array != null ){
      int size = array.size();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think not getting the array size where u try to transfer the data or mismatch the type.
 Your mapping of object is not correct. Plz check your mapping again.